# How to know a branch's version of NPM package in repository?

Tags: npm

There is an Ionic package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic

It can be installed like:

```
$ npm install -g ionic
```

On the page it shown that latest version is `1.7.8 is the latest of 278 releases`.

But you also can install alpha branch like:

```
$ npm install -g ionic@alpha
```

That would install 2.alpha-*.

But how do I know what is the latest version of this branch in repository (not 
the one that installed)? I want to check if I have the latest version and to know when a new version is published.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
npm install -g driftyco/ionic-cli#beta
```

I not found alpha branch, only beta...but you can install branchs this way

Comment: I don't need to instal it, need to update and before updating to check if new version was published. The `npm install -g ionic@alpha` works just fine for installation - it's from here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/installation/